# An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]"

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I just get started with springboot and I am stuck with this problem. No data is passing through the controller. I just want to jump to the "index.html" page, which is a template and downloaded from bootstrap.

Here is my controller.

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping({"/", "/index.html"})
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

The index.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th=http://www.thymeleaf.org
      xmlns:sec=http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security
      xmlns:shiro=http://www.pollix.at/thymeleaf/shiro

      html lang=en xmlns:th=http://www.thymeleaf.org
      xmlns:sec=http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security
      xmlns:shiro=http://www.pollix.at/thymeleaf/shiro>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <title>Signin Template for Bootstrap</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link th:href="@{/css/signin.css}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body class="text-center">
        <form class="form-signin" action="dashboard.html">
            <img class="mb-4" th:src="@{/img/bootstrap-solid.svg}" alt="" width="72" height="72">
            <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
            <label class="sr-only">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="" autofocus="">
            <label class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
            <div class="checkbox mb-3">
                <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
        </label>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
            <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">© 2017-2018</p>
            <a class="btn btn-sm">中文</a>
            <a class="btn btn-sm">English</a>
        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

The stack trace is as follows.

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]" - line 6, col 9)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:239) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) [thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) [thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1401) [spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145) [spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084) [spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) [spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_291]
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: (Line = 6, Column = 9) Malformed markup: Attribute "lang" appears more than once in element
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleAttribute(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:549) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.ParsingAttributeSequenceUtil.parseAttributeSequence(ParsingAttributeSequenceUtil.java:300) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseOpenElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:153) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:710) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
```

I wonder is there any problem with my dependencies?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ljh</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot</name>
    <description>springboot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Your initial <html> tag doesn't look ok. Almost as if it was copied twice. (Also, using quotes might help)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was really stupid.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception cause shows what is wrong:

> Malformed markup: Attribute "lang" appears more than once in element

You have this in your HTML:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th=http://www.thymeleaf.org
      xmlns:sec=http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security
      xmlns:shiro=http://www.pollix.at/thymeleaf/shiro

      html lang=en xmlns:th=http://www.thymeleaf.org
      xmlns:sec=http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security
      xmlns:shiro=http://www.pollix.at/thymeleaf/shiro>
```

Change it to:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th=http://www.thymeleaf.org
      xmlns:sec=http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security
      xmlns:shiro=http://www.pollix.at/thymeleaf/shiro>
```